# How to use case expression or should go for any other option

Tags: oracle

I have a table that looks something like this, Report_Table:

| Report_DEFINITION_NAME | Report_CORE_NAME | COMPLETION_STATUS | COMPLETION_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ReportAD | AD | Success | 14-01-2019 |
| ReportBB | BB | Error | 24-06-2022 |
| ReportAD | AD | Error | 19-03-2020 |
| ReportR5 | R5 | Success | 04-06-2022 |
| ReportG8 | G8 | Error | 04-06-2022 |
| ReportR5 | R5 | Success | 18-11-2020 |
| ReportLH | LH | Success | 07-09-2019 |
| ReportU6 | U6 | Error | 12-05-2022 |
| ReportAD | AD | Success | 23-09-2021 |

I wanted to pull data from Report_table. If COMPLETION_STATUS is Success it should give the latest Success COMPLETION_DATE table date and if it has Error it should give the last Success COMPLETION_DATE table date as well as the Error date. Something like

> select  Report_DEFINITION_NAME, Report_Core_name, COMPLETION_STATUS, COMPLETION_DATE,

> CASE:
> WHEN COMPLETION_STATUS='Success' THEN latest Success COMPLETION_DATE
> WHEN COMPLETION_STATUS='Error' THEN last Success COMPLETION_DATE
> WHEN COMPLETION_STATUS='Error' THEN latest Error COMPLETION_DATE
> END

> from Report_Table;

the output should be in a single query identified by core name or definition name.

Comment: Are you using both MySQL and Oracle? If not, remove one of the tags. Also, it would help if you - along with source data - posted result you expect.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Do you need what you requested, separately for each report (as identified by core name)? It would help if you would post the exact desired output from the sample data you posted.

Comment: the output should be in a single query identified by core name or definition name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I have used IN clause to solve my problem and no Case expression.

Getting the max value in a select statement and calling that statement using IN clause from my parent select statement solved my problem.
something like:

```
SELECT 
  a.*,
  a.completion_date,
  b.completion_date AS last_success_date
FROM report_table a, report_table b
WHERE a.report_definition_name = b.report_definition_name
AND a.completion_date IN 
(
  SELECT MAX(su.completion_date) 
  FROM report_table su 
  WHERE su.completion_status = 'Success'
  AND b.report_definition_name = su.report_definition_name
)
ORDER BY a.completion_date DESC;
```

Comment: Why are you joining b? Thus you get the a row repeated with all dates of the report. Is that what you want? (Besides: Don't use 1980's comma-separated joins. Use explicit joins like  `[INNER] JOIN`, `LEFT [OUTER] JOIN`, etc. instead.)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).